# Python Error "the following arguments are required"

Tags: python, arguments

the program is expected to extract images from an MP3 file, and I am not sure how to utilize it in its current form. I get the error "the following arguments are required: mp3File" I have tried to initialize a mp3File argument but have not seen success in this. How can I properly add this argument into my code so it will run properly? I currently have two mp3 files in the same directory as this program.

```
import os                           # Standard Operating System Methods
import argparse                     # Command Line Argument Parsing
from   struct import *              # Handle Strings as Binary Data 
import string                       # Special string Module
import time                         # Date Time Module
import sys

class ID3():

    def __init__(self, theFile):
        try:
            self.fileName = theFile
            with open(theFile, 'rb') as mp3File:    
                self.fileContents = mp3File.read()
        except Exception as err:
            print("Could not process input file: ", theFile, err)
            quit()

        #Strip off the first 10 characters of the file
        stripHeader = self.fileContents[0:6]  
    
        #now unpack the header
        id3Header = unpack('3sBBB', stripHeader)
    
        self.hdr         = id3Header[0]
        self.version     = id3Header[1]
        self.revision    = id3Header[2]
        self.flag        = id3Header[3]
        
        if (self.hdr == 'ID3' or self.hdr == b'ID3') and self.version in range(2,5):
            self.id3 = True
        else:
            self.id3 = False
            print("MP3 File type not supported")
            quit()

        # Get Size Bytes and unpack them
        stripSize = self.fileContents[6:10]    
        
        id3Size = unpack('BBBB', stripSize)

        self.id3Size = self.calcID3Size(id3Size) + 10    
        
        # check the unsync flag
        if self.flag & 0x60:
            self.unsync = True
        
        # check the extended header flag
        if self.flag & 0x40:
            self.extendedHeader = True
        
        # check the experimental indicator
        if self.flag & 0x40:
            self.experimental = True             
        
        self.processID3Frames()
        
        return
```

Main Program

```
def main():
    
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('mp3File')
    theArgs = parser.parse_args()
     
    mp3File = theArgs.mp3File
    
    # Verify the file exists and is a file
    if not os.path.isfile(mp3File):
        sys.exit(mp3File+" Not Found")
    
    # Verify we have a valid output directory for images
    curDir = os.getcwd()
    if not os.path.isdir("./images"):
        # if not then attempt to create it.
        try:
            os.mkdir("./images")
        except Exception as err:
            sys.exit("Cannot create output directory: "+err)
        
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the shortest code necessary to replicate the issue.

Comment: I have condensed the program and ran it to ensure the error is replicated, thank you for the comment!

Comment: What command are you using to run this program?

Comment: I am using Wing IDE, but have also had the same error produced on Visual Studio Code as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a argument correctly, just pass it in the command line:

```
> python.exe myprogram.py sample.mp3
```

The `sample.mp3` is the main (positional) argument. If you wanna depth-in and know more about argparse, check [this section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#core-functionality) of the docs.

In this way, the `theArgs.mp3File` should contain "sample.mp3":

```
> python.exe myprogram.py sample.mp3

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('mp3File')
    theArgs = parser.parse_args()
    print(theArgs.mp3File)  # "sample.mp3"
```

Any questions, feel free to ask!

Comment: I appreciate the solution! I had not thought to run my program through command line. I was stuck using Wing IDE/Visual Studio Code and had not thought to run the program outside of that. Thank you.